# Dealing with Multiple Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I currently have a method that updates a Redis table based on a `Future[String]`.

```
  def update(key: String, timeStamp: Long, jsonStringF: Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) = {

    jsonStringF.map { jsonString =>
      val historyKey = "history." + key
      val tempKey = "temp." + key

      val tran = redisClient.transaction()
      tran.zadd(historyKey, (timeStamp, jsonString))
      tran.del(tempKey)
      val f = tran.exec()
      f.onComplete {
        case Success(suc) => dlogger.info(s"Updated $historyKey and deleted $tempKey successfully ....")
        case Failure(ex) => dlogger.warn(s"Error updating tables", ex)
      }
    }
  }
```

Now I've two `Future[String]` (`jsonStringF1` and `jsonStringF2`) and I want to update two different tables.

```
  def update(key: String, timeStamp: Long, jsonStringF1: Future[String], jsonStringF2: Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) = {
 ....

}
```

I want to update another table (`"another." + key`) with `String` in `jsonStringF2`. How can I do that ?

**UPDATE**: Is the code below correct?

```
  def update(tableKey: String, timeStamp: Long,  jsonStringF1: Future[String], jsonStringF2: Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) =
  {

    for {
      a <- jsonStringF1
      t <- jsonStringF2

      historyKey = "history." + tableKey
      anotherKey = "another." + tableKey + 

      tempKey = "temp." + tableKey
      tran = redisClient.transaction()
      _ = tran.zadd(historyKey, (timeStamp, a))
      _ = tran.zadd(anotherKey, (timeStamp, t))
      _ = tran.del(tempKey)
      f = tran.exec()
    } yield ()
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use **for** loop, as you described

   ```
   def update(tableKey: String, timeStamp: Long,  jsonStringF1: Future[String], jsonStringF2:Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) = {
       for {
           a <- jsonStringF1
           t <- jsonStringF2
       } yield {
           val historyKey = "history." + tableKey
           val anotherKey = "another." + tableKey

           val tran = redisClient.transaction()
           tran.zadd(historyKey, (timeStamp, a))
           tran.zadd(anotherKey, (timeStamp, t))
           tran.del(tempKey)
           tran.exec()
       }
   }
   ```
2. As an alternative to **for** you can also use scala/async (https://github.com/scala/async) and write your code like this

   ```
   def update(tableKey: String, timeStamp: Long,  jsonStringF1: Future[String], jsonStringF2:Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) = {
       async {
           val a = await(jsonStringF1)
           val t = await(jsonStringF2)

           val historyKey = "history." + tableKey
           val anotherKey = "another." + tableKey

           val tran = redisClient.transaction()
           tran.zadd(historyKey, (timeStamp, a))
           tran.zadd(anotherKey, (timeStamp, t))
           tran.del(tempKey)
           tran.exec()
       }
   }
   ```

Which will also be nonblocking.
Async has slight advantage, since

> async blocks are compiled to a single anonymous class, as opposed to a
>   separate anonymous class for each closure required at each generator.

Answer (score 3):

Your can collect multiple futures using a `for`:

```
val f1: Future[String] = ...
val f2: Future[String] = ...

for {
  a <- f1
  b <- f2
} {
  // Code to execute when both f1 and f2 complete
  // a and b are available here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just 2 Futures you can zip them:

```
def update(tableKey: String, timeStamp: Long,  jsonStringF1: Future[String], jsonStringF2:Future[String], redisClient: RedisClient) = {

    val jsons = jsonStringF1.zip(jsonStringF2)
    jsons map {
      case (a, t) => 
        val historyKey = "history." + tableKey
        val anotherKey = "another." + tableKey

        val tran = redisClient.transaction()
        tran.zadd(historyKey, (timeStamp, a))
        tran.zadd(anotherKey, (timeStamp, t))
        tran.del(tempKey)
        tran.exec()
    }
}
```